# Enforcing use of a package management system when developing with a team

Tags: python, github, workflow, dependency-management, collaboration

I work on a large python code base with several teammates. We are often installing or updating dependencies on other python packages, and inevitably this causes problems when someone else updates their master branch from git, or we deploy on a new system.

I've seen many tools available for deploying environments on new computers, which are great. The problem is that these tools only work if everyone is consistently updating the relevant files (e.g. `requirements.txt`, `setup.py`, tarballs on a PyPI server...) every time they update or add a package.

We use Github's pull request system for code reviews. What would be great would be some means of indicating to the reviewer that the dependency structure has changed, prompting the reviewer to check for the necessary updates (also good would be to build in a checklist that the reviewer has to complete, reminding them to do the check).

How have other folks dealt with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would enforce the use of tools with a network proxy or network ACL, to block public sites and stand up internal services like gitlab, bitbucket, GitHub enterprise, or internal pypi server, to force the use of certain standards.

Comment: Oh interesting! So for example block normal pip installation so people have to add wheels to our own installation server?